# MS Excel : Formula in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Hi I am trying apply a function in MS excel (Proper Function)

But When i write this function and use fill handle to copy the same to other cells i am getting the same out put in all the copied cells.
[image]

But when i click on the cell the reference is Ok. But the result is different.

[image]

What should i Do?

Comment: Is Recalc set to manual ? Does F9 solve the issue ?

Comment: Yup, if it is, either set it to automatic or press F9 each time after typing a formula.

Comment: Hi Thank you Jerry and iDevelop..this works. But how to i set Recalc to manual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the tab "Formulas" and click on the little triangle next to "Calculation options". There select "Automatic".